# UIScrollview reduces in size if I go back to parent view in horizontal orientation

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am suffering from this weird thing that happens to my UIScroll view if I go back to maintableview while in horizontal format..

basically when I come back to the subview which has the scrollview on it it only has approximating half the original size of the scrollview..

and I have no idea why.

here is the method in my uiscrollview which loads the scrollview and images that I display inside them.

```
- (void)loadImage:(NSString *)myImageName
{
//    //Create scrollview

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    scrollView.delegate = self;

//    containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 700)];


    //Create scrollviewimage
    if ([myImageName isEqualToString:@"one"]) {
        image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hardout.png"]];
        containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
        //        NSLog(@"1");
    }
    if ([myImageName isEqualToString:@"two"]) {
        image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"kiakaha.png"]];
        containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 580, 460)];
//        NSLog(@"2");
    }
    if ([myImageName isEqualToString:@"three"]) {
        image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"browheresmychips.png"]];
        containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 560, 660)];
//        NSLog(@"3");
    }

    //Add subview
    [containerView addSubview:image];
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    scrollView.contentSize = containerView.frame.size;
    [scrollView addSubview:containerView];

    //scrolling
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 31.0;
    scrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor;
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scrollView.minimumZoomScale];

    //highrachy
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}
```

basically this method is being set from the parent view indexPath selection. every think works fine so long as i go back to the parent view while in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be because of the autoresizingMask that you have used.